# Changing formula (with consecutive relative references) into an array formula so it will work with google forms input

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas, google-sheets-formula

How do I change the following formula into an array formula so it will work even when new rows are added by google forms?

```
=if(SUMPRODUCT($D5:$D7) < 1,"Bad","Good")
```

Background:
Column D contains either TRUE or FALSE values. The formula simply looks back and if there are 3 Falses in a row, I need the output to be "Bad". This works fine if I copy it down. *But*, this sheet is linked to a google form and google adds a new row for new responses.

For another part of the sheet I figured out that if I make an array formula, then the *array formula* will take effect even though google inserts a new row (no need to copy down). Example of what works: `=ArrayFormula(DAY($C2:C) = $A$1)`. This works from $C2 all the way down the rest of column C and so works with rows inserted by google forms.

How can I make the first formula work like the second while still looking back at the last three relative values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the direct equivalent would be

```
=ArrayFormula(if(A4:A="","",A4:A+A3:A+A2:A))
```

but this doesn't work - it will always need more rows to be inserted at the bottom of the sheet.

```
=ArrayFormula(if(A4:A="","",A4:A+A3:A999+A2:A998))
```

does work, but only for a certain sheet size.

You could look ahead like this though:

```
ArrayFormula(if(A2:A="","",A2:A+A3:A+A4:A))
```

A more complicated way to get round it is to do a vlookup on the row number like this:

```
=ArrayFormula(if(row(A2:A)<4,"",if(A2:A="","",A2:A+vlookup(row(A2:A)-2,{row(A2:A),A2:A},2,false)+vlookup(row(A2:A)-1,{row(A2:A),A2:A},2,false))))
```

(you need to add if statements to make it report "Good" or "Bad")

```
=ArrayFormula(if(row(A2:A)<4,"",if(A2:A="","",IF(A2:A+vlookup(row(A2:A)-2,{row(A2:A),A2:A},2,false)+vlookup(row(A2:A)-1,{row(A2:A),A2:A},2,false),"Good","Bad"))))
```

Comment: Actually your first version fixed my problem. I only ever use this with google form responses so google is always inserting a row at the bottom of the sheet for a new response. Your first solution works great for me.